# Vector not changing with "AES/CBC/pkcs7padding" in Java

Tags: java, aes, bouncycastle, cbc-mode

I'm using the mode "AES/CBC/pkcs7padding" in java to communicate between 2 devices.

When the communication is setup, one of the two devices will allocate a random IV and send it to the other device. The recipient will use this IV to instantiate an encryptionCipher and a decryptionCipher (see code below).

NB: Here I'm putting only the code for encryption but we have similar code for decryption.

The IV vector has been sent at the beginning of the communication. We then want the 2 devices to exchange encrypted messages without sending the IV anymore.
If our understanding is correct, as long as no message is lost, both device should know what is the current "vector" to use in the XOR.

However, the Java code is not working as we expecting:
If I call encrypt() 2 consecutive times, it produces the same encrypted data.
This is not what we expected because we thought that the result of the first encryption would be the "vector" of the second encryption (XOR between this vector and the plainText as indicated on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#CBC).

Is our understanding wrong? Did we miss something in the implementation?

```
private Cipher mEncryptionCipher;

private void createEncryptionCipher(byte[] iv) {

    mEncryptionCipher = null;

    try {
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        mEncryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/pkcs7padding", "BC");
        mEncryptionCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, mAESKey, ivParameterSpec);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


private byte[] encrypt(byte[] data) {

    if (mEncryptionCipher == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Invalid mEncryptionCipher!");
        return null;
    }

    try {
        int sizeOfEncryptedData = computeLengthAfterPKCS7Padding(data.length);
        byte[] encodedData = new byte[sizeOfEncryptedData];

        int cipherBytes = mEncryptionCipher.update(data, 0, data.length, encodedData, 0);

        //allways call doFinal
        cipherBytes += mEncryptionCipher.doFinal(encodedData, cipherBytes);

        return encodedData;

    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ShortBufferException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (STException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Why? If this is anything but a toy project just use TLS!

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#doFinal--) clearly states: "Upon finishing, this method resets this cipher object to the state it was in when previously initialized via a call to init. "

Comment: That exactly what worries me @JamesKPolk - if the OP didn't read something as simple as how to maintain the state; what other things have been missed?

Comment: Because of the reset of the state after the doFinal() command, this CBC implementation is in my opinion pointless. We lose all the benefit of CBC. 
@Boris the Spider Thanks, I will look if we can use TLS.

Comment: Blaming the tools because you use them incorrectly is not constructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have suggested, just use TLS if at all possible.

Otherwise, at least take a lesson from TLS' design (mistakes). In TLS 1.0 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246), the CBC cipher state was maintained across separate records, which I think is what you are trying to do across your 'packets'. In TLS 1.1 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) this was changed so that each record contained an explicit IV. Each record's IV "SHOULD be chosen at random, and MUST be unpredictable". So each record is encrypted independently.

Please note in particular this section of the security analysis in RFC 5246:

> F.3.  Explicit IVs
>
> [CBCATT] describes a chosen plaintext attack on TLS that depends on
> knowing the IV for a record.  Previous versions of TLS [TLS1.0] used
> the CBC residue of the previous record as the IV and therefore
> enabled this attack.  This version uses an explicit IV in order to
> protect against this attack.

There are other pitfalls awaiting you too, so I return to my first suggestion: use TLS if at all possible.

EDIT: Oops, TLS 1.1 RFC is actually https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346, which has the same F.3 section.

Comment: Good find, excellent example of where doing something that seems obvious is actually a bad idea.

Comment: “the cipher state was maintained across separate records, which I think is what you are trying to do across your packets”
Yes I confirm that it is what we wanted to do. Despite Boris’s view, we didn’t want to create our own crypto but this is how we had understood that CBC should work. 
According to your message, our understanding was correct and it is how it was implemented in TLS 1.0. Then some attacks were found and it explains why it was changed in TLS 1.1 and why java implementation resets the state.
That’s clear now, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by Boris the Spider and James K Polk, doFinal() resets the state of the cipher object so, if we do a new encryption, it restarts from the original IV which is not the wanted behavior for CBC.

I have tried the solution below and it works. I'm retrieving the last encrypted block and using it as IV for the next encryption.

```
private byte[] mEncryptionIV = new byte[INITIALIZATION_VECTOR_SIZE];

private byte[] encrypt(byte[] data) {

    try {
        int sizeOfEncryptedData = computeLengthAfterPKCS7Padding(data.length);
        byte[] encodedData = new byte[sizeOfEncryptedData];

        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(mEncryptionIV);
        Cipher encryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/pkcs7padding", "BC");
        encryptionCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, mAESKey, ivParameterSpec);

        int cipherBytes = encryptionCipher.update(data, 0, data.length, encodedData, 0);

        //always call doFinal
        cipherBytes += encryptionCipher.doFinal(encodedData, cipherBytes);

        // The last encrypted block will be used as IV for the next encryption
        System.arraycopy(encodedData, encodedData.length-AES_BLOCK_LENGTH, mEncryptionIV, 0, mEncryptionIV.length);

        return encodedData;

    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ShortBufferException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (STException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Whilst this seems to be secure, as much as I understand CBC mode ciphers, it smells a lot of rolling your own crypto. Furthermore I don't understand the reasoning behind it, as you are basically running CBC over CBC - why not just use a single session and push data into it, or better yet use `Cipher(Input/Output)Stream`.

Comment: Also note that you have next to no meaningful error handling, an error during encryption will cause the method to return `null`; the VI will not be reset. The next encryption attempt will then be with the same IV, and that's Game Over.

Comment: “Furthermore I don't understand the reasoning behind it, as you are basically running CBC over CBC”
No no it only continues the CBC chaining:

With the code indicated in the question, the IV is reset after each doFinal() call so after each encryption. That means that all the messages exchanged by my devices will always be encoded with the same IV. That doesn’t look very secure.

That’s why we have done this change. Every time the encrypt() method is called, the new block is XORed with the ciphertext of the previous block (as described by CBC).

Comment: BTW, in our implementation the data are split into packets and each packet is acknowledged by the receiver so we can detect when an ecrypted packet is lost and resend it (using the same encrypted data).
This is important to avoid the risk that the sender and the receiver don’t do the same XOR.

Comment: I see that my question has been downvoted. Was it so stupid or not well written?

Comment: CBC is a mode of operation, which is my point - you're chaining chains. And whilst it looks very similar to how the underlying chain works; I don't know what subtleties you have missed in implementation that could cause problems for the algorithm - encryption is notoriously picky. As I said above, throw this all away and use TLS - you obviously don't know enough to be inventing your own cryto and I wouldn't trust randoms on the internet to review it in any case. This is a solved problem, just use the industry standard solution.

Comment: As to the downvote - can only speculate as to the motivation, but generally questions that arise from not reading the manual are likely to attract downvotes.

Comment: As to you mitigation, that wasn't my point - your solution presupposes that the encryption succeeded and the sending fails. My point is that if encryption throws an exception your error handling is such that any further attempt to encrypt will use the same IV. I do hope that the code is only illustrative, as the error handling is not good at all - print to stdout and returning `null` is something I would expect in an undergraduate coding exercise.

Comment: I have looked at TLS but I think that I will not be able to use it because we don’t have a TCP/IP stack. Our communication is done over NFC.

Comment: TLS doesn't care about TCP/IP - it can work by carrier pigeon. Having said that though, it does change things. I don't know much about NFC comms, but the chips in smart card, for example, are very low powered - don't know if TLS would be too much for them.